# Crear metodo personalizado en una Entidad @Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tengo  la entidad Usuario  a la cual le quiero crear un  metodo personalizado:

```html
@Entity
public class Usuario{

private String nombre;
private String apellido;

@Transient
private String nombreCompleto;


public Usuario(){
this.nombreCompleto = this.nombre + " "+ this.apellido ;
}


}
```

Como tal esto me genera error  y no se muestra en mis  resultados de las consultas.

¿ Que debo usar para que esto funcione ?

Comment: Que error te genera??? Algo mas de informacion sería util para poder solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

me  respondo a mi mismo.

Después  de tanto investicar encontre este decorador:

@PostLoad

Asi que esto me funciono de maravillas:

```html
@PostLoad
private void postLoad() {
      this.nombreCompleto = this.nombre + " "+ this.apellido ;
}
```

El postLoad Espera  a que la entidad se carge y puedes  usar las propiedades ya cargadas.